# Animated gif texture in 3ds max

Tags: animated-gif, animated, 3dsmax

and thanks in advance.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have created an animated .gif in Photoshop to use as a texture map for a model in 3ds max 2010. The Texture displays well enough in max and in renders, however it is not animated. I had it working at one point, but I cannot figure out what I might have changed in the settings that would cause animated textures to not play. That being said; I am very interested in learning of other file types that are better suited for animated textures in Max.

Comment: "I don't know what I am doing wrong."  Do you have any examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Any other file type is a better fit. Max can create a sequence of any image type

Answer (score 1):

Try use image sequence (png,tiff) 
Save each frame animation as file with names

some_name__000.ext
some_name__001.ext
some_name__002.ext

and load first as image sequence.
Max will create IFL file when you load texture as image sequence

Next time you can load IFL

IFL is text file, so it is easy to edit